# Converting Shapefile to GeoJSON. Both OGR and Mapshaper converters give errors

Tags: shapefile, geojson, convert, error

I'm trying to convert a large Shapefile (120 MB) to GeoJSON.

OGR converter gives an error that says process time took over 15 seconds, so process was cancelled.

Mapshaper gives the following error: `File size of .shp doesn't match size in header`

What can I do now?  I'd prefer not installing any desktop software to do a simple conversion.

Comment: Your shapefile is corrupted. Contact whoever delivered the data for you and ask to send valid data.

Answer (score 6):

If a python script is an option for you, then this will do the trick fast:

```
import geopandas as gpd
file = gpd.read_file("file.shp")
file.to_file("file.json", driver="GeoJSON")
```

Comment: If ogr can't read the dataset, then geopandas probably won't be able to either as it's based on ogr.